# How to find arg of a non-circular shape

Tags: complex-analysis

Expert,

Not sure if the title suits what I am going to ask here.

Basically I have a conformal mapping function that transforms a unit circle into an ellipse with $b/a=1/3$, where $a$ and $b$ are the major and minor axis of the ellipse.:

$$z=x+iy = e^{i\theta} + \frac{0.5}{e^{i\theta}} = \xi+i\eta$$

where $\theta=[0..2\pi]$.

The following figure shows that the unit circle is transformed into an ellipse according to the above equation.

[image]

**Question:**
Suppose that I only have the coordinate of the ellipse, i.e. {$x,y$} (thus the arg $\omega$ can be obtained) by knowing only the above function, would it be possible to find out the corresponding arg $\theta$ of the circle?

Comment: It looks like what you mean is that $z = x + iy = e^{i\theta}$ is transformed into $w = \eta + i\xi$ (it would have been better to have $\xi$ and $\eta$ the other way round, but never mind), where $w = z + \frac1{2z} = x + iy + \frac{x - iy}2$, so $\eta = \frac{3x}2$ and $\xi = \frac{y}2$. If that *is* what you meant, then you might be able to answer your own question (a perfectly normal thing to do), simply by looking at $\tan\theta$ and $\tan\omega$.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I have fixed it. Now, it is written as $w = \xi + i\eta$